# Vertical Alignment of footer in fancyhdr package

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a `twosided` document in which I use a customized footer with the fancyhdr package. The odd thing is that the inner footer, containing chapter/section info and the outer footer containing page number are vertically non-aligned. The page number is always higher than the text. However, if I use fancyhead instead of fancyfoot, everything is perfectly aligned in the header! No idea why this does not work in the footer the same way.

Can anyone help?

I attach a short script showing the problem. For ease, both header and footer are active to show the difference.

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Petra

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,11pt,openany,DIV=calc,ngerman,twocolumn,xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\lkopf}[2]{\markboth{\ref{#1} #2}{}}
\newcommand{\rkopf}[2]{\markright{\ref{#1} #2}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
    \fancyhf{} % remove everything
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{myheadings}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\rightmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Greetings}
\label{kap:greetings}
\lkopf{kap:greetings}{Greetings}

\twocolumn[
\section*{Greetings A}\label{gruss_A}
]
\rkopf{gruss_A}{Mr. A}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\twocolumn[
\section*{Greetings B}\label{gruss_B}
]
\rkopf{gruss_B}{Mr. B}
\lipsum[0]
\lipsum[100]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to be a crosspost: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/22400/fancyhdr-seitenzahl-auf-gleicher-hohe-wie-rest-der-fusszeile There is also an answer (German).

Answer (score 1):

The issue does not exist if you use package `scrlayer-scrpage` for header and footer. Note that its usage is suggested for KOMA-Script classes.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a5,
  open=any,
  DIV=calc,
  ngerman,
  twocolumn,
  %xcolor=dvipsnames% unused/unknown option
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[
  manualmark,% set marks manually
  headsepline=.5pt,
  footsepline=.5pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\ifoot{\headmark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\newcommand{\lkopf}[2]{\markboth{\ref{#1} #2}{}}
\newcommand{\rkopf}[2]{\markright{\ref{#1} #2}}

\begin{document}

\addchap*{Greetings}
\label{kap:greetings}
\lkopf{kap:greetings}{Greetings}

\twocolumn[
  \addsec*{Greetings A}\label{gruss_A}
]
\rkopf{gruss_A}{Mr. A}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\twocolumn[
  \addsec*{Greetings B}\label{gruss_B}
]
\rkopf{gruss_B}{Mr. B}
\lipsum[0]
\lipsum[100]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you are using unnumbered chapters and sections. So the reference to this chapters and sections are empty. Maybe you want to use `\nameref`?

Example with `\nameref` in `\rkopf`:

```
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcommand{\lkopf}[2]{\markboth{\ref{#1} #2}{}}
\newcommand{\rkopf}[2]{\markright{\nameref{#1} #2}}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That did the job. Did not know the scrlayer-scrpage package. Thanks a lot for pointing out!

Comment: @Petra If the answer solves your issue then you can upvote and maybe accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to overcome this issue but I don’t know why this is happening, maybe someone here can tell us what’s going on. One possible solution is to put the content of the headers and footers inside an `\mbox` and adjust the `\fboxsep` to 0pt.

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\lkopf}[2]{\markboth{\mbox{\ref{#1} #2}}{}}
\newcommand{\rkopf}[2]{\markright{\mbox{\ref{#1} #2}}}
```